# Quill editor - insert content in quill editor at the cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angularjs, typescript

I am using quill editor. suppose i have a select box where i can select value from it, so that it can be inserted into the quill editor. But I want the value to be inserted at the cursor, instead of at the end or beginning of the content.

Comment: Hi there. Try adding more code into your question so that people can better understand your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//to get the index of selection

var range = quill.getSelection();

//to insert the text at cursor

quill.insertText(range.index, text, 'bold', true);

Comment: What if I want to insert and render HTML same like above? is there any way for appending HTML. I have asked same question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75363753/how-to-append-and-render-the-html-in-quill-editor

Answer (score 3):

Here you are, check out the codesandbox demo below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-brook-m2m80?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

**Bind the reference of quill editor**

```
@ViewChild(QuillEditorComponent, { static: true })
editor: QuillEditorComponent;
```

**Get the cursor position and insert text**

```
onChangeOption(key: string) {
    const index = this.editor.quillEditor?.getSelection()?.index; // get cursor position
    if (index !== undefined) {
      this.editor.quillEditor?.insertText(index, key); // insert text after the index
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to insert and render HTML same like above? is there any way for appending HTML. I have asked same question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75363753/how-to-append-and-render-the-html-in-quill-editor