# How to append and render the HTML in quill editor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, quill

Hi I am trying to append and render the HTML at current cursor. But I am not able to append the HTML. I tried everything. But not able to get solution.

```
<quill-editor #quillEditor  [(ngModel)]="content" [modules]="modules"> </quill-editor>
<button (click)="addChip()">Add Chip</button>

<div id="toolbar">
  <!-- Add buttons as you would before -->
  <button class="ql-bold">B</button>
  <button class="ql-italic">I</button>
  <button class="ql-emoji">I</button>
  <span class="ql-formats">
    <select class="ql-color"></select>
    <select class="ql-background"></select>
  </span>
  
</div>
```

> ts

```
 @ViewChild('quillEditor', { static: false }) editor: QuillEditorComponent;
 constructor() {
    this.modules = {
      'emoji-shortname': true,
      'emoji-toolbar': true,
      toolbar: {
        container: '#toolbar',
      },
    };
  }
addChip() {
    const cursorPosition = this.editor.quillEditor.getSelection().index;

    const delta = this.editor.quillEditor.clipboard.convert(
      `<p>Your HTML code here</p>`
    );
    console.log('delte', delta);

    this.editor.quillEditor.updateContents(
      { index: cursorPosition, length: 0 },
      delta,
      'api'
    );
  }
```

My quill versions:

```
 "ngx-quill": "^3.4.0",
"quill": "^1.3.7",
    "quill-emoji": "^0.2.0",
```

I tried everything, I don't know what I am doing wrong in this. If anyone knows any solution or you have stackblitz, please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

you should add information about cursor position to delta, not as parameter of updateContents method.

install
`npm i quill-delta`

change

```
import Delta from 'quill-delta';

...

addChip() {
    const cursorPosition = this.editor.quillEditor.getSelection().index;

    const clipboardDelta = this.editor.quillEditor.clipboard.convert(
      `<p>Your HTML code here</p>`
    );

    const delta = new Delta().retain(cursorPosition).concat(clipboardDelta);

    console.log('delte', delta);

    this.editor.quillEditor.updateContents(
      delta,
      'user'
    );
  }
```